# Are the following standard five connectives { "and", "or", "not", "implies", "if and only if"} complete in fuzzy logic?

Tags: logic, fuzzy-logic

I am currently in a Logic class and was assigned this question.

In class we define **complete** as a set of connectives that could generate every truth function.

My answer to this question is no, the set of logical connectives is not complete in fuzzy logic. My reasoning behind this answer is the fact that .5 is .5-preserving. You can never get anything different from a .5. More clearly,

.5 and .5 = .5

.5 or .5 = .5

Not.5 = .5

.5 implies .5 = .5

.5 if and only if .5 = .5

Is this justification enough?

Comment: There are many different [fuzzy logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-norm_fuzzy_logics). Not all of them validate the equations you give. However, they all validate $x \to x = \top$. Yoiu probably need some kind of cardinality argument to prove what you are trying to prove when you have worked out exactly what it means.

Comment: @RobArthan Not all fuzzy logics have $x\to x=T$, because, for example, some of them define $p\to q$ to be the same as $\neg p\vee q$, and if $\vee$ means maximum, then all the operations are $\frac12$-preserving, just as Suzanne says. It follows by induction on formulas that every formula in that language will have value $\frac12$ whenever all the inputs have value $\frac12$.

Comment: I am taking Hajek's $BL$ as the most general fuzzy logic. We must be talking at cross-purposes here. Logics derived from a t-norm are bound to satisfy $x \to x = \top$ aren't they.

Comment: Well, in the fuzzy analogue of Kleene logic, we have $\frac12\to\frac12=\frac12$, and I believe that this is the version of fuzzy logic that the OP is using.  But as you say, there are many fuzzy logics, and many of them disagree on $p\to q$.

Comment: I think I would follow Hajek and not consider Kleene's logic (and other similar logics of undefinedness) as fuzzy logic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic seems to support my view. But thanks for opening my eyes to alternative readings of terminology that I thought was widely agreed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that fuzzy logic means some sort of infinite-valued logic.  So, I don't know what the vast majority of outputs for the connectives you have for all inputs in the infinite truth set.  George J. Klir and Bo Yuan in *Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy Logic* write

"The insufficiency of any single infinite-valued logic (and therefore the desirability of a variety of these logics) is connected with the notion of a complete set of logic primitives  It is known that there exists no finite complete set of logic primitives for any one infinite-valued logic.  Hence, using a finite set of primitives that defines an infinte-valued logic, we can obtain only a subset of all the logic functions of the given primary logic variables."

This might get contrasted with Lukasiewicz-Wajsberg-Slupecki three-valued logic which has functionally complete semantics, and a complete and independent axiom set.